# Implications of two probabilistic inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Consider three sequences of random variables $(X_n)_n$, $(Y_n)_n$, and $(W_n)_n$, respectively with mean $\mu_x, \mu_y, \mu_w$. Assume that for each $\alpha>0$
$$
\Pr\Big(Y_n \leq \mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\leq \alpha,\\
\Pr\Big(W_n \geq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\leq \alpha.
$$
Also assume that $Y_n\leq X_n\leq W_n$. Could you help me to  show that
\begin{equation}
\label{HI3}
\Pr \Big(\mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}  \leq X_n \leq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big) \geq 1-\alpha \quad ?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking the complement in the two inequalities (assuming $Y_n,W_n$ are absolutely continuous), we get :

$$\Pr\Big(Y_n \geq \mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\geq 1- \alpha,\\
\Pr\Big(W_n \leq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\geq 1 -\alpha.
 $$

Next observe that because $Y_n\leq X_n\leq W_n$, we have for any real numbers $C,C'$ that
$$ \Pr\Big(X_n \geq C\Big)\geq \Pr\Big(Y_n \geq C\Big)\\
\Pr\Big(X_n \leq C'\Big)\geq \Pr\Big(W_n \leq C'\Big) $$

Putting these two observations together with $C,C'$ respectively equal to $\mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} $ and $\mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}  $, we get
$$\Pr\Big(X_n \geq \mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\geq 1- \alpha,\\
\Pr\Big(X_n \leq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big)\geq 1 -\alpha. $$

Finally, by the [well known inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities) $\Pr(A\cap B)\ge \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - 1 $ for two measurable events $A$ and $B$, we conclude that
$$\Pr \Big(\mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}  \leq X_n \leq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Big) \geq 2-2\alpha+1 = 1-2\alpha $$
Which is almost the desired inequality up to a factor $2$ in front of $\alpha$. If we want to get rid of it, then we should instead consider the event
$$\Pr \Big(\mu_y -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\alpha}}  \leq X_n \leq \mu_w+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\alpha}} \Big) \geq 1-\alpha  $$